# Get perimeter out of irregular group of shapes

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I'm working on groups of shapes (think groups of city blocks) that are almost contiguous, like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is to get the shape of the outer perimeter of this group. With more regular forms, this was almost working:

```
per_df = gpd.GeoSeries(df.geometry.unary_union.convex_hull).boundary
```

Bringing something like this:

[image]

But on an irregular shape it brings this:

[image]

Is there some way to "fuse" or join my shapes into one so it is easier to calculate its perimeter/boundary?

Here's a simpler reproducible example:

```
p1=Polygon([(0,0),(10,0),(10,9.8),(0,9.8)])
p2=Polygon([(10.2,10),(20,10),(20,20),(10.2,20)])
p3=Polygon([(10,10),(9.8,20),(0,10)])

df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p1,p2,p3])
per_df = gpd.GeoSeries(df.geometry.unary_union.convex_hull).boundary
ax = df.plot()
```

I'd like to get the perimeter of this group of shapes, even though there's a bit of separation between them:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How accurate should the boundary be? Maybe you can use something like closing in image processing. First you extent all your polygons with geopandas.buffer, take the union of all polygons and finally decrease your polygon by using buffer with a negative number.

Comment: Quite accurate, because I can't put a household across the street inside my boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
buf = df.geometry.buffer(10) #or a value that suits you better
unary = buf.unary_union
print(unary.length)
```

You can also buffer with -10 (or the chosen value) the unary union to be closer to the real shape before calculating the length.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is working pretty well

Answer (score 1):

You could try performing a buffer on your geometries so that they overlap, followed by a dissolve, generating a single geometry. You could take the boundary of this geometry. Optionally, a negative buffer can be applied to get the boundary fitting closer to the original data, although some details may be lost

```
p1=Polygon([(0,0),(10,0),(10,9.8),(0,9.8)])
p2=Polygon([(10.2,10),(20,10),(20,20),(10.2,20)])
p3=Polygon([(10,10),(9.8,20),(0,10)])

df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p1,p2,p3])
df["geometry"] = df.buffer(0.5)
dissolved_df = df.dissolve()
dissolved_df["geometry"] = dissolved_df.buffer(-0.5)
per_df = dissolved_df.boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the output as close as possible to the original shapes and/or need a solution that scales well for large input files, you could try [geofileops.dissolve_within_distance](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.dissolve_within_distance.html#geofileops.dissolve_within_distance)

Sample script:

```
from pathlib import Path
import geofileops as gfo
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely import Polygon

# Prepare input
p1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 9.8), (0, 9.8)])
p2 = Polygon([(10.2, 10), (20, 10), (20, 20), (10.2, 20)])
p3 = Polygon([(10, 10), (9.8, 20), (0, 10)])
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[p1, p2, p3])
input_path = Path("input.gpkg")
df.to_file("input.gpkg")

# Process
output_path = Path("output.gpkg")
gfo.dissolve_within_distance(input_path, output_path, distance=1, gridsize=0.0)

# Visualize
result_df = gpd.read_file("output.gpkg")
ax = result_df.plot(color="green")
df.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor="blue", facecolor="none")
plt.show()
```

Result in green, input in blue:

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of [geofileops](https://github.com/geofileops/geofileops).